# Zend Cache - problem with deleting cache files

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-cache

I have an strange problem with Zend Cacke (File Backend) running on linux with apache and php 5.2

The files are stored in /myspace/tmp1

Directory has the persmission:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 nobody nogroup 8192 2010-09-20 13:35 tmp1
```

The created temp file has the following permissions:

```
-rw------- 1 nobody nogroup  317 2010-09-20 13:40 content---a51607ba255692370eae1155c7f45856
```

If if i do:

$cache->clean(); inside my script, than the method returns true, but the file is not removed (no error in php error log).

On my local development machine running under win xp everything works fine. I think it is some kind of permission problem? The Apache is running as "nobody"

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Regardless of whether the file is there or not, is the cache broken?

Comment: File permissions are not the trouble. PHP is working through apache. Permissions are set correctly. Are you running safe mode?

Comment: is safe mode an problem?

Comment: i am totally unsure , but it might related to SELINUX ??

Comment: Did you try `$cache->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL);`? This should be default but who knows... What happens if you try to `unlink` the file manually?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL` as by default it cleans only outdated AFAIK.